# display the image (portrait,landscape) as it is in UIImage using Swift

Tags: ios

i fetching images from gallery, I want to display the image as it is (i.e. if the image is portrait I want to display in portrait. If image in landscape, I want to display in landscape) using Swift.

I find the image is portrait or not:

```
if (myImage.size.width > myImage.size.height){

    print("Landscape")
    self.currImageV.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```

Comment: `UIImage` is already displayed as it is in image view when using content modes that preserve aspect ratio (such as `scaleAspectFill`). What exactly is you issue, what is your current result and what is your expected result?

Comment: if  image is in landscape,i want to show that image in imagaeview should be landscape way,not in potrait.but i serached in google for this there is no example

Comment: i getting a photos from gallery and load it into collection view,i click the image in collection view and show it in a UIImageview for editing purpose.

Comment: in this uiimageview i want to show that image in imagaeview should be landscape way,not in potrait and if image is potrait mode show that in potrait itself...please help me

Comment: So you basically want to force the user to turn device landscape when working on landscape image and portrait when working on portrait image?

Comment: no my app is only potarit mode, just change the oreintation of imageview only

Comment: u can see this iphone camera roll image,when u take pic in landscape,the imageview also landsacpe,not to force the user turn device

Comment: It is still pretty much impossible to understand what you are trying to achieve here but maybe what you are looking for is `myImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi*0.5)` which will rotate it by 90 degrees.

Comment: thank you..but i want to transform only the uiimageview not image.by using the above image is also get transform from original position(uiimage is roted to 90 degrees)

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong object. It should be:
`self.currImageV.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi*0.5)`

Comment: thank you its worked for me..little bit i change the value

Comment: self.currImageV.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi*0.0) this is the code i used,the uiimage is not rotated ..can u explain the meaning for this code

Comment: The meaning of the code you posted is equal to `self.currImageV.transform = .identity` which is a default. A transform will transform a view with a given matrix. Using rotation `.pi*0.5` will rotate it by 90 degrees, using `-.pi*0.5` will do the same in another direction, `.pi` will do a 180 degrees and then `.pi*2.0` will have no effect again... Why would you use a zero?

Comment: thank you for spending your valuable time for me...its worked i used .pi*2.0